# Partial view not working properly for Menu's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In my asp.net mvc app I have made a partial view for displaying menu's. It is like this.

```
@model InstaFood.Core.Institution
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="" role="navigation">
        <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">
                <h1 class="show-for-small-only"><a href="#">Menu</a></h1>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="left">
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Dashboard", "Institution", new { id = @Model.Id })</li>


                @*weird bug of id not being passed on to the view patients view*@



                  <li class="has-dropdown">
                    <a href="#">View</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Patients", "ViewPatients", "Institution", new { id = @Model.Id })</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
</div>
```

As you can see in the comment that I am having this issue that the id is not passed to ViewPatients view. It works here

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Dashboard", "Institution", new { id = @Model.Id })
```

The link produced looks like this

```
http://www.instafood.com/Institution/Dashboard/00204a50-ef7b-46bb-8104-b887c91d7f71?Length=11
```

I am not sure why it appends Length=11 here but at least it works.

But the same thing doesn't not work here

```
@Html.ActionLink("Patients", "ViewPatients", "Institution", new { id = @Model.Id })
```

The link produced here looks like this

```
http://www.instafood.com/Institution/ViewPatients?Length=11
```

My controller action for ViewPatients is

```
  public ActionResult ViewPatients(String id)
    {
        Institution institution = Institution.Get(id);
        return View(institution);
    }
```

Any one know why this is happening and how it can be solved?

Comment: Can you post your controller's action method ?

Comment: Yeah sure, just edited my question.

Comment: can you show your `RouteConfig`? I think it's the most obvious place where Length=11 can be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your `@Html.ActionLink` as shown :-

```
@Html.ActionLink("Patients", "ViewPatients", "Institution", new { id = Model.Id }, new {})

@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Dashboard", "Institution", new { id = Model.Id },new{})
```

as shown above add `new{}` an extra empty htmlattribute object as 5th parameter in `@Html.ActionLink` and your problem will solve ;)

OR as correctly pointed by **webnoob** in comments section instead of `new{}` we can also use `null`.

Comment: It works, the length=11 is gone and it started working. But can you explain what was happening?

Comment: @mohsinali1317..actuaally the `@Html.ActionLink()` is treating your third parameter as object route but actually it is a controller name that is why its showing `Length=11` because `Institution` is `11` characters long,so if we use `new{}` as shown in my answer then it will use a proper overload of actionlink having first parameter as linktext,second as actionname,third as controller ,fourth as object route and fifth which is empty object of htmlattribute.

Comment: I didn't downvote but no need for `new{}` here, just pass null.

Comment: @webnoob...yes we can pass null also.. but there is no harm in passing new{}